# How to show views block output in drupal menu?

Tags: views, 7

I have views block and I want to display its output in sub menu when user mouseover on main menu. I on't know how to implement it. Is there any module for it?
Please help tell me how can I display views block in drupal menu?.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build a dropdown menu, you can have a look at [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus). This module provides blocks that automatically generates dropdown menus from a selected menu.

If you want to build something more particular than a basic dropdown menu based on Drupal menu system, you should add your block to a hidden region in your html and then move it in the DOM with jquery.

You can do something like that:

```
// Get menu item
menu = jQuery('#selector .to li');

// Get block
block = jQuery('#block-block-myblock');

// Force hide
block.hide();

// Append the block to the menu item
block.appendTo(menu);

// Show / hide menu on hover
menu.hover(function(){ // Function to be run on mouse hover
  block.fadeIn();
}, function(){ // Function to be run on mouse out
  block.fadeOut();
});
```

Hope this will help you !
Cheers

Comment: Don't forget to properly wrap your JavaScript code to be executed on page load as a behavior. See http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors

Answer (score 1):

If you actually wants to use view to build (part of) a menu with drop-down effect, the [Views build menu](http://drupal.org/project/views_build_menu) module may suit your needs when combined with a module like [Nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) or [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish).

Answer (score 1):

[menu_minipanels](http://drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels) should be the answer. With this module you can print any block (that comes from panel) under the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [Menu Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_views) module.

This approach is rather simple: Attach a view to a menu item.
There are a few modules out there that really attempt to make mega menus simple, but their UI's are completely cluttered. We designed this module to give the admin the power to attach ANY view to ANY menu item. Once the markup is there, then your theme can style it however it wants.